# What's the best way to repeat an array multiple times in DolphinDB to form a matrix?

Tags: dolphindb

To repeat an array `[1,2,3]` x times along the row dimension and y times along the column dimension in DolphinDB, right now I use:

```
k=1 2 3
take(k, size(k)*x*y)$(size(k)*x):y
```

This looks pretty messy. I am wondering if there is a more intuitive way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is function `repmat`. For your example:

```
repmat(matrix(k),x,y)
```